# Systemd service to run Python script not accepting arguments for python script

Tags: python, raspbian, systemd, systemctl

I'm trying to run a Python script as a service using systemctl on a Raspberry Pi Zero running Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). My service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=pi_sensor
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/pi_sensor/python/read_sensor_data.py -p /home/pi/Documents/pi_sensor/url/marley_1.tsv
Restart=always
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, whenever the script runs the "-p" argument is ignored (e.g. if I print the argument I get "none"). If I run this exact script from a shell it works fine. It also works through systemctl if I hard code the argument into the Python script. Because of this, I think I'm messing up the systemd argument syntax for adding arguments to Python scripts. I also tried putting the file path after -p in single quotes, which didn't work. Thanks for your help!